# I am trying to loop through my counter to create a dynamic sql query which should finally look like

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I am trying to loop through my counter to create a dynamic sql query which should finally look like `110 111 112`

I am trying to use this approach to get the final query but doesnt seems to work

```
declare @CurrentRow int
set @CurrentRow =0;
declare @RowsToProcess int
declare @FinalHistoricalQuery varchar(5000)
WHILE @CurrentRow<3
BEGIN      
   SET @FinalHistoricalQuery =' select 11'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
   SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
END

SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = left(@FinalHistoricalQuery,len(@FinalHistoricalQuery)-6)
exec (@FinalHistoricalQuery)
```

The final ouput that I am looking for is `110 111 112` but it comes as `112`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing to `append` the string that is generated in each loop so you will get only the string generated in last loop will be stored in the variable.

Also initialize the `variable` with `empty string`.

```
declare @FinalHistoricalQuery varchar(5000)=''
....
SET @FinalHistoricalQuery +=' select 11'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
....
```